# set row's value become column and fill it based on other column's row's value

Tags: python, dataframe, transform, transpose, one-hot-encoding

i have a dataframe like this:

```
id  category    year    freq
101 1           2020    1
101 1           2021    1
202 2           2020    2
202 2           2021    6
203 3           2021    2
```

I need to transform the dataframe based on id, category and year's value and fill the year's value with frequency for the year. The desired output is:

```
id  category    2020    2021
101 1           1       1
202 2           2       6
203 3           0       2
```

i have tried using one hot encoding, but the i can't fill each year's column with frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a job for [`df.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). Notice that we'll use `fill_value=0` to replace missing values with 0 (to match your expected output):

```
>>> df.pivot_table(values="freq", index=["id", "category"], columns="year", fill_value=0)
year          2020  2021
id  category            
101 1            1     1
202 2            2     6
203 3            0     2
```